# Need to update SF record from a VF selectlist

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 3 selectList on a VF page. In the controller I have the personID which is the id of the record that I want to put the values of what a user selects in these 3 fields.

1) give each of the 3 fields a handle. When I tried using ID I got an error.
2) What code would I put in my save method in order save it? Update on Program__c Set field1=tosomething, field2=tosomething, fields3=tosomething where id = :personID or something like that?

```
 <apex:PageBlock title="Choose Your Preferred Seminar(s) for {!progName}">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveItem}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelAction}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <h1>First Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList value="{!names}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
            <p />
                    <h1>Second Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList  value="{!names}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
             <p />
                    <h1>Third Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList value="{!names}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
</apex:PageBlock>

      </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of three names to hold values, i would point them to the exact fields to be assigned.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!person.preference1__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
<apex:selectList value="{!person.preference2__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
<apex:selectList value="{!person.preference3__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
```

Here `preference1__c`, `preference2__c` & `preference3__c` are the fields to be updated in the Person object which id you have. It would automatically assign the values selected to the fields.

Then in your controller you can update it like

```
update person;
```

Note;

`person` should be declared as `public` with getters and setters which should of same type as `personId`. The `personId` should be assigned to this as `person = new Person__c(id = personId);`

Hope it helps.